# How do I target an alias from a restriction, with the QueryOver api?

Tags: nhibernate

As far as I know, the QueryOver api does not allow you reference an alias by name, but rather you use a typed object.  How can I add a restriction to my query that targets the alias?

For example, I would like to accomplish something similar to the following:

```
var query = session.QueryOver<Person>().JoinQueryOver(x => x.Dogs, () => dogAlias);

return query.Where(Restrictions.Disjunction()
                       .Add(Restrictions.Like("Name", searchQuery, MatchMode.Anywhere))
                       .Add(Restrictions.Like("dogAlias.Name", searchQuery, MatchMode.Anywhere)));
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

instead of:

```
Restrictions.Like("dogAlias.Name", searchQuery, MatchMode.Anywhere)
```

use:

```
Restrictions.On(() => dogAlias.Name).IsLike(searchQuery, MatchMode.Anywhere)
```

So, the complete query would become:

```
var query = session.QueryOver<Person>()
            .JoinQueryOver(x => x.Dogs, () => dogAlias);

return query.Where(Restrictions.Disjunction()
                .Add(Restrictions.On<Person>(p => p.Name).IsLike(searchQuery, MatchMode.Anywhere))
                .Add(Restrictions.On(() => dogAlias.Name).IsLike(searchQuery, MatchMode.Anywhere)));
```